# Is it possible to view what tokens and the amount of tokens somebody is holding?

Tags: tokens

Is it possible to view what tokens and the amount of tokens somebody is holding?
If you know his or her Ethereum address? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. E.g. type the address into https://etherscan.io.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before but I somehow missed the button "view tokens"... I'm closing the question.